# jQuery: links in a new window

Tags: jquery, window, new-operator

This is the simplest of issues, but I can't for the life of me figure out why this code won't work. All I'm trying to do is to get the links in a div to open in a new window.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#block-aggregator-feed-1 .content > a').click(function() {
        $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#block-aggregator-feed-1 .content > a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

you are assigning target after the click event is fired. Do it before, right after document ready.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#block-aggregator-feed-1 .content > a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
});
```

Just set it on .ready, instead of on click.